# Identify usage of gradle dependency

Tags: gradle

I am cleaning up dependencies from the build.gradle file for a big-sized Java project. How do I identify the usage of a certain dependency in the code-base ?

Comment: See the [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that comes to my mind right away would be to remove the dependency and run `compile` to see if it was needed. You can of course skip checking the ones you are sure that are needed. If there's a lot of suspects you can comment out several at a time and if build fails and you don't know which one is a valid dependency, you can use binary search ;) to speed up the process.